# align-content not working on flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a row-direction flexbox nested in a column-direction flexbox, but when I want to use `align-content` in the child, it doesn't work.

When I replace `display:flex` of the parent by a `display:block`, it works.

In the code below, we can see that `.row` `align-content: flex-end;` doesn't work. But if I replace the `.column` `display: flex;` with `display: block;`, the `align-content: flex-end;` works.

Is it possible to fix this, please?

```css
body {
    background-color: grey;
}

.column {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: stretch;
    background-color: green;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: red;
}

.row-test {
    min-height: 200px;
}

span {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<body class="column">
    <section class="row row-test">
        <span>Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test</span>
        <span>Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test</span>
    </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 32):

The fact that `align-content` "works" when the primary flex container is switched to `display: block` is simply a browser bug.

It shifts the flex items to the bottom, as desired, but *only in Firefox*.

In Chrome it doesn't do anything, which is the correct behavior (per the spec).

And in IE11 it shifts the items to the top (also nonconformant).

These are bugs and inconsistencies that shouldn't be relied upon for guidance, as they don't help to explain how the `align-content` property works.

---

In a ***single line flex container***, like the one in the question, `align-content` has no effect. The property to use is `align-items`.

In a ***multi-line flex container***, the property to use is `align-content`.

Also, the `align-self` property is closely related to `align-items`. One is designed to override the other. They both function together.

*From the spec:*

> [**8.3. Cross-axis Alignment: the `align-items` and `align-self` properties**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property)
>
> `align-items` sets the default alignment for all of the flex container’s items, including anonymous flex items. `align-self` allows this default alignment to be overridden for individual flex items.
>
> [**8.4. Packing Flex Lines: the `align-content`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property)
>
> The `align-content` property aligns a flex container’s lines within the
>   flex container when there is extra space in the cross-axis, similar to
>   how `justify-content` aligns individual items within the main-axis.
>   *Note, this property has no effect on a single-line flex container.*

---

In terms of this question, forget about `align-content`. It's useless (unless your flex items wrap).

Simply use `align-items: flex-end` (or `align-self: flex-end` on the `span`'s):

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: green;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: flex-end;        /* will work when items have wrapped */
  align-items: flex-end;          /* adjusted; works when items in one line */
  background-color: red;
}
.row-test {
  min-height: 200px;
}
span {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: orange;
  /* align-self: flex-end;     this would also work on single line container */
}
```

```html
<body class="column">
  <section class="row row-test">
    <span>Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test</span>
    <span>Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
          Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test</span>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: align-content is not align-items. Apparently. Thx.

Comment: Not working as of 2023 in Chrome. It is displayed similar to the example given by topic starter.

Answer (score 24):

Maybe you want to use `justify-content` instead of `align-content`

Comment: I think this should be the best answer (at 2020).
Using justify-content solve problem in almost  all browsers.
Note: remember it will works only if there are more than one element in flex container

Answer (score 6):

You need to add flex-wrap: wrap; to work align-content

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to set a height on the parent container fo your flex items to get align-content to work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would you mind elaborating; it'd help if you gave a working example not just mention flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Probably late to answer this, but elaborating on [Billy Mitchell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57810351/7977581), you can set the parent container with a specific height or if you want to completely center it,

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <div>Child 2</div>
</div>
```

You can structure and replace the values of the properties of the above snippet according to your needs. Here is a [complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) which helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To add to things to try, with me it worked when I removed `flex-direction: column;`. Things are still stacked in a column and `align-content` applies now.

Answer (score 0):

In react, this is how I managed it. The parent div needs to occupy the whole intended space in order to spread child divs in it (width:"100%", height:"100vh")
Children need to have width 100% in order to be wrapped.

```
     <div style={{display:"flex", flexWrap:"wrap", alignContent:"space-between", width:"100%", height:"100vh",  textAlign:"center"}}>
        <div style={{height:"50px",width:"100%", border:"solid 1px red", }} className="header">
            <div>name: SSname</div>
            <div> Score</div>
        </div>
        <div style={{height:"140px",width:"100%" }} className="content">
            <div>
                Please wait for activity to start
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style={{height:"50px", width:"100%",  border:"solid 1px red"}} className="footer">
            <div>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a constantly repeated problem with align-content, although it is not used too much. to make align-content work correctly, you must make
flex-wrap: wrap