# Not able to vertically align items in flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I am learning to use flexbox and I am not able to align content vertically inside of the class `.headercontent`. it seems to honor everything else like `justify-content` but ignores `align-content`. I searched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37226787/align-content-not-working-on-flex-items/52621741) thread and this seems to suggest that the parent should have height explicitly set. I have set height by setting `flex-basis` and `flex-grow` and a `min-height`. But still by `div` containing the `h1` is stuck to the top of the `header`. I want that green div to be in the vertical center of the `header`. what am I doing wrong?

```css
html {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 100%;
            line-height: 1.2em;
          }
          body {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            align-items: stretch;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: #cdc9c1;
          }
          header {
            background-color: #a99879;
            flex-basis: 10%;
            flex-grow: 1;
            min-height: 20px;
          }
          main {
            background-color: #5b431a;
            flex-basis: 80%;
            flex-grow: 8;
          }
          footer {
            background-color: #77613c;
            flex-basis: 10%;
            flex-grow: 1;
          }
          .headercontent {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            background-color: green;
            min-height: 20px;
          }
          .navstyle {
            list-style-type: none;
          }
```

```html
<html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <header>
          <div class="headercontent">
            <h1>This is the header</h1>
        </div>
        </header>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>section1</li>
            <li>section2</li>
            <li>section3</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <main>
          <p> this is the main body</p>
        </main>
        <footer>
          <p> this is the footer </p>
        </footer>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the codeine link to my work https://codepen.io/knows_not_much/pen/rNxXoOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want that green div to be in the vertical center of the header. what
> am I doing wrong?

Your `header` element is taking up 10% height of `body`. Your `.headercontent` does not take up the entire defined height of the `header`. Therefore, it is going to sit at the top. To address this, you can assign the `header` element to be a flex container and that is where you assign `align-items: center; justify-content: center` properties

```
header {
    background-color: #a99879;
    flex-basis: 10%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex; /* add these */
    align-items: center; /* add these */
    justify-content: center; /* add these */
}
```

Assign `width: 100%` to the `.headercontent` afterwards (as needed) if you must have the green background take up the space

Comment: thanks. if I do it this way how do I know which one is for parent and which one is for self?  so here in your code `flex-basis` and `flex-grow` are for parent flex and others are for self flex. I had created the `headercontent` class only to avoid mixing the settings for the two `flexboxes`

Comment: your suggestion works and I get what I want but it is just mixing up the settings of parent and child flexboxes.

Comment: The `flex-basis` & `flex-grow` properties mainly are for flex items (i.e., children of a flex container/parent). I get what you are saying - it will not get mixed up for itself or for its children because these properties are only for oneself _provided_ that it is a flex item inside a flex container. In contrast to properties such as `align-items` or `align-self`: these properties can be for itself or for its children (if it is a flex container) & its behavior easily be distinguished based on the verbiage: example,the word "self"